# How to translate "stay healthy "

Tags: translation, english-to-german, pronoun, formality

How to translate:

***" Please stay healthy and safe during these times"*** or ***"I hope you and Frau Mueller are staying healthy and safe during these times"***

*My versions:*

1) Bleiben Sie  gesund und sicher in dieser zeit.

Answer (score 2):

**Bleiben Sie gesund** or **Ich hoffe Sie bleiben gesund** is fine.

**Bleiben Sie sicher** could sound a little odd. Wishing to **stay safe** is uncommon to me. Then it also means **stay sure** which makes no sense. So it could be quite confusing, I'd just leave it away.

Comment: Why would "stay safe" be uncommon for you? Suppose I wished to tell someone to stay safe. Would it be inappropriate to say "Bleiben Sie sicher"?

Comment: @Naomi It is not inappropriate to say that. But I am not sure if I have ever heard that in German. As there are two meanings and this expression is quite rare at least to me, I can imagine the other person perhaps won't understand it as expected.

Comment: @Naomi: To make puck's remark more explicit: Safe, sure, and secure *all* translate to "sicher", and the primary way "sicher sein/bleiben" will be understood is the meaning of "sure" (i.e. to be convinced of, certain about sth.). You could say "bleiben Sie in Sicherheit", but that sounds overly dramatic, as if the addressee had to shelter from gunshots or meteorite strikes.